# How to store and get a array cookie with Angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, cookies, setcookie

I need to push value in array and stored in  cookies when user click on GO button.

if value is more than 10  i need to remove the first added item in the array and updated cookies , displayed in front end.

but i'm tried multiple ways some time i am getting values sometimes not , the code is not consistently working.

please find below the code

**JS:**

```
$scope.lastorder = $cookies['lastorder'];

$scope.cookiefunction=function(val) {
                /*
                $scope.lastorder.push(val);
                if($scope.lastorder.length > 4){
                        $scope.lastorder.shift();
                }
                $cookies.putObject('lastorder',$scope.lastorder);*/


                $cookies['lastorder']={'productname':val};
                $scope.lastorder = $cookies['lastorder'];
                if($scope.lastorder.length > 4){
                        $scope.lastorder.shift();
                }
                //$cookies['lastorder']={$scope.lastorder};
                $scope.lastorder = $cookies['lastorder'];
        };
```

**in Frond end:**

li ng-repeat="x in lastorder">{{x.productname}}

Comment: what is the exact issue?

Comment: @Sajeetharan:cookie value not properly stored and not able to get in front end

Comment: Can you create a plunker for your issue

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/Ejk3sxn90J3QfVPJ30aH?p=info

Comment: Is this plunkr working as expected?  If not, what should be different?  http://plnkr.co/edit/fx36Srw27nvq3pfecB04?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Plunkr: [Click here](http://plnkr.co/edit/nrcLbVFDMJbwtPFm9Dyk?p=preview)

```
  var DemoApp = angular.module('DemoApp', ['ngCookies']);

    DemoApp.controller('DemoController', function ($cookies, $scope, $log) {
      var cookieName = 'orderList';//
      $scope.orderList = $cookies.getObject(cookieName) || [];

      $scope.saveCookie = function (val) {
        if ($scope.orderList.length >= 10) {
          $scope.orderList.shift();
        }

        $scope.orderList.push({productName: val}); 
        $cookies.putObject(cookieName, $scope.orderList);
      }
    });
```

Comment: Initial load i'm getting "length is undefined" error in my page

Comment: code is not working , becaue   i  am using angular above 1.4 version

Comment: @CodeMan i have modified the code to cater for angular 1.4